# Retrieve Phone number from text file irrespective of format

Tags: java, python, phone-number, libphonenumber

I want to retrieve phone numbers from a text file. I am trying to use the  [third party python version of google's phone number library](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers). But it is not able to retrieve numbers with spaces between them for ex. - "+91 – 9871127622".

Is there any way around it?

If not, I wanted to install [Google's original library of phone numbers](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)
but I don't know how to install and include it in my code(no instructions are provided)

My python code is as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import phonenumbers
import os
import re
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]
fp =open(file_name,"r")

for line in fp:
    for match in phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(line,None):
        print match
```

Comment: If spaces are the only issue, then did you consider removing them?

Comment: The one time a regex is a good idea!!!! :-)

Comment: Please provide a sample text.

Comment: It's not only spaces.The regex I was using was `regex = re.compile(r'(\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4})')
` Sample Phone numbers include (91)XXXXXXXXXX , 0XXXXXXXXXX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to quickly cleanup unwanted characters in your input.

My regular expression is this: `[^\\d]`. It matches any non-digits in the input. I'm replacing each matching character with an empty string. So, we will be left with only the digits in the end.

Here's something to get you started:

```
public class CleanPhoneNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputPhoneNumber = "+91 – 9871127622";
        String validPhoneNumber = cleanup(inputPhoneNumber);
        System.out.println(validPhoneNumber );
    }

    public static String cleanup(String inputPhoneNumber) {
        return inputPhoneNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
    }

}
```

You can further improve the regular expression.

PS: I'm not into Python, but you can use a similar approach there too.

> **Update**, based on *Ole V.V.*'s comment:

```
public static String cleanup(String inputPhoneNumber) {
    String cleanedUp = inputPhoneNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
    if(inputPhoneNumber.startsWith("+")){
        return "+" + cleanedUp;
    }
    return cleanedUp;
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: We will probably still want to know whether the phone number contains a `+` before the first digit since this would indicate that there is a country code.

Comment: I actually need the country code as well. But it should detect the phone even if '+' sign  isn't mentioned.

Comment: Yup. This will retain the country code and the `+ ` sign before it.

Comment: Which library are you using in this ? The original one by google or third party ? If you are using the original google one, can you please tell me how to use it, There are no instructions available on their page.

Comment: I'm not using any library. It's standard Java an is quite rudimentary.